# jQuery's toggle <button id="button"> and <div id="button"> differences?

Tags: jquery, html

**question***

What is the difference between using a `<button id="button">` with `jQuery` toggle and using `<div id="button">` with `jQuery` toggle?

I am asking because both options seem to be working. Is it a bad habit to use divs like that?

Comment: button and div are just two different type of object, that is all

Comment: @bansi So is it fine for me to use div like that then? Or should I always stick to using buttons in such cases, e.g wrapping button around a div box I would like to act as a button for toggling purposes?

Comment: A `div` element shouldn't be used as a button.

Answer (score 1):

`<button id="button">` is the element `**button**` referred to by the *id* `button`.

`<div id="button">` is the element `**div**` referred to by the *id* `button`.

Either element can be referred to using `$("#button")` in JQuery since you are telling it to look for an element with the *ID* `button`. And ur case ur code would work on *any* element as long as its *assigned ID* is `button`.

Applying the JQuery `toggle()` function on the element will simply change the the `display` of the found element from either `display:block` to `display:none` **or** from `display:none` to `display:block`, with a sliding visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

button and div are two different things

with this you are giving id to button

```
<button id="button">
```

and with this you are giving id to div

```
<div id="button">
```